# Need a file system metadata layer for applications

Tags: python, file, metadata

I'm looking for a metadata layer that sits on top of files which can interpret key-value pairs of information in file names for apps that work with thousands of files.   More info:

- These aren't necessarily media files that have built-in metadata - hence the key-value pairs.
- The metadata goes beyond os information (file sizes, etc) - to whatever the app puts into the key-values.
- It should be accessible via command line as well as a python module so that my applications can talk to it.
- ADDED: It should also be supported by common os commands (cp, mv, tar, etc) so that it doesn't get lost if a file is copied or moved.

Examples of functionality I'd like include:

- list files in directory x for organization_id 3375
- report on files in directory y by translating load_time to year/month and show file count & size for each year/month combo
- get oldest file in directory z based upon key of loadtime

Files with this simple metadata embedded within them might look like:

- bowling_state-ky_league-15_game-8_gametime-201209141830.tgz
- bowling_state-ky_league-15_game-9_gametime-201209141930.tgz

This metadata is very accessible & tightly joined to the file.  But - I'd prefer to avoid needing to use cut or wild-cards for all operations.

I've looked around and can only find media & os metadata solutions and don't want to build something if it already exists.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at extended file attributes? See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes

Basically, you store the key-value pairs as zero terminated strings in the filesystem itself. You can set these attributes from the command line like this:

```
$ setfattr -n user.comment -v "this is a comment" testfile
$ getfattr testfile
# file: testfile
user.comment
$ getfattr -n user.comment testfile
# file: testfile
user.comment="this is a comment"
```

To set and query extended file system attributes from python, you can try the python module xattr. See: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xattr

**EDIT**
Extended attributes are supported by most filesystem manipulation commands, such as cp, mv and tar by adding command line flags. E.g. cp -a or tar --xattr. You may need to make these commands to work transparently. (You may have users who are unaware of your extended attributes.) In this case you can create an alias, e.g. alias cp="cp -a".

Comment: This looks fabulous.  But, from I've found extended attributes aren't supported by tar, cp or mv - so can be easily lost when processing files.  I suspect for this reason they are a poor fit for applications which move the files around a lot.  Which is what I'm targeting.

Comment: @KenFar: `cp --archive` preserves xattrs. Also `tar --xattrs`.

Comment: Thanks - any idea about performance?  I'm hoping to write some code today to see how long it takes to pick up extended attributes for 1000 files.

Comment: No I have never done performance tests with extended attributes. I will be interested to know your results.

Comment: @KenFar did you do any tests with extended attributes so far? I'd like to know what you ended up with, and what the performance was.

Comment: Sorry - haven't had a chance to complete my tests yet.   I found some odd usability issues (bugs?) and lack of documentation in one of the modules consumed more time than I had.

Answer (score 2):

[As already discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12433404), xattrs are a good solution when available. However, when you can't use xattrs:

### NTFS alternate data streams

On Microsoft Windows, xattrs are not available, but [NTFS alternate data streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=NTFS&oldid=511837447#Alternate_data_streams_.28ADS.29) provide a similar feature. ADSs let you store arbitrary amounts of data together with the main stream of a file. They are accessed using

```
drive:\path\to\file:streamname
```

An ADS is effectively just its own file with a special name. Apparently you can access them from Python by specifying a filename containing a colon:

```
open(r"drive:\path\to\file:streamname", "wb")
```

and then using it like an ordinary file. (Disclaimer: not tested.)

From the command line, use Microsoft's `streams` program.

Since ADSs store arbitrary binary data, you are responsible for writing the querying functionality.

### SQLite

SQLite is an embedded RDBMS that you can use. Store the `.sqlite` database file alongside your directory tree.

For each file you add, also record each file in a table:

```
CREATE TABLE file (
    file_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    path TEXT
);
```

Then, for example, you could store a piece of metadata as a table:

```
CREATE TABLE organization_id (
    file_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    value INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(file_id) REFERENCES file(file_id)
);
```

Then you can query on it:

```
SELECT path FROM file NATURAL JOIN organization_id
WHERE value == 3375 AND path LIKE '/x/%';
```

Alternatively, if you want a pure key-value store, you can store all the metadata in one table:

```
CREATE TABLE metadata (
    file_id INTEGER,
    key TEXT,
    value TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(file_id, key),
    FOREIGN KEY(file_id) REFERENCES file(file_id)
);
```

Query:

```
SELECT path FROM file NATURAL JOIN metadata
WHERE key == 'organization_id' AND value == 3375 AND path LIKE '/x/%';
```

Obviously it's your responsibility to update the database whenever you read or write a file. You must also make sure these updates are atomic (e.g. add a column `active` to the `file` table; when adding a file: set `active = FALSE`, write file, fsync, set `active = TRUE`, and as cleanup delete any files that have `active = FALSE`).

- The Python standard library includes SQLite support as the [`sqlite3`](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) package.
- From the command line, use the `sqlite3` program.

Comment: Thanks - I don't care about windows so won't need NTFS.  And I'm really looking at very simple metadata that could exist in a file name - so that it can be maintained within atomic operations and kept close to the file.

Answer (score 0):

the Xattr limits on the size(Ext4 upto 4kb), the xattr key must prefix 'user.' on linux.
And not all file system support the xattr.

try [iDB.py](https://github.com/clouddb/idb.py/) library which wraps the xattr and can easily switch to disable xattr supports.